# how to use ft.aggregate in node-redis

Tags: redis, node-redis

I've been trying to use ft.aggregate in node-redis, specifically APPLY and I cant find any good example.
Plus, if anyone knows how to use parsetime function in redis I would appreciate it

For the parsetime problem, I have tried the next command:

```
ft.aggregate idx:example * APPLY parsetime(@date) as date.
```

And I keep getting:
Error: Something went wrong

For the node-redis problem:

```
redis.ft.aggregate('idx:example, '*',{STEPS:[{type:AggregateSteps.APPLY,
```

and the rest I'm not sure- what do I need to write in the expression clause, same for the as

Answer (score 2):

I poked around with this a bit and got it to work from the command-line. I learned that there are a couple of important tidbits:

1. You need to LOAD the field you want to call APPLY on in your query.
2. You need specify the format of the string and, for whatever reason, `%FT%TZ` won't work.
3. Since the format is in quotes, you need to wrap the entire APPLY argument in quotes.

See below:

```bash
redis.local> FT.AGGREGATE idx:example * LOAD 1 date APPLY "parsetime(@date, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')" as date
```

For the Node Redis code, I was able to get this to work:

```js
const results = await redis.ft.aggregate('test:index', '*', {
  LOAD: [ 'date' ],
  STEPS: [{
    type: AggregateSteps.APPLY,
    expression: "parsetime(@date, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')",
    AS: 'date'
  }]
})
```